# Calculate $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \exp\{-x^{2}-\lambda x^{4}\}\ dx$

Tags: calculus, special-functions, bessel-functions, gaussian-integral

I am trying to find a way to calculate the $\phi^4$ perturbative Gaussian integral in quantum field theory without using Mathematica.

The integral is $I(\lambda)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \exp\{-x^{2}-\lambda x^{4}\}\ dx$

Mathematica shows

$I(\lambda)=\frac{e^{\frac{1}{8\lambda}}K_{\frac{1}{4}}(\frac{1}{8\lambda})}{2\sqrt{\lambda}}$, for $\Re(\lambda)>0$, where $K_{n}(x)$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind.

Comment: May be I misunderstand but Mathematica does not have anything to do. This is the result. May be, are you looking for soma approximations for the result. Could you clarify ?

Comment: What is the range of $\lambda$ of interest for your work ?

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Sorry I cannot understand what you mean. Probably you have never seen such an integral before. If you have encountered such an integral, please tell me how to get the result. I got it from mathematica.

Comment: Sorry ! I misunderstood the question. I thought than you wanted to compute or approximate $I(\lambda)$ then my question. Is Mathematica able to generate the antiderivative ?

Comment: @Claude Leibovici, I am sorry for my English expressions. I realized people always misunderstood my questions. Now I still cannot understand what you mean. I don't know what antiderivative is. I am not very familiar with using mathematica. I am just curious how one can do that pretty nasty integral by hand and get the result which I got from mathematica.

Comment: Do not worry ! My English is more than surely worse than your ! Antiderivative=primitive or undefined integral. I thought that you wanted to evaluate the result as given by Mathematica. Now, if you ask : how to get this expression by usual methods (by hand), I am curious too ! Cheers. Please, let me know if you get an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained in [this lecture notes](http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~xiyin/Site/Notes_files/2008%20GSS%20talk%20-%20p2+x4.pdf) by Xi Yin in 2008.

The partition function is given by

$$\mathcal{Z}(\hbar)=\int dx e^{-\frac{1}{\hbar}S(x)}\equiv\int_{C}\frac{dz}{2\pi i}e^{-z/\hbar}B(z).$$
where $B(z)$ is the modified Borel transform, given by

$$B(z)=-\int\prod_{i=1}^{N}dx_{i}\frac{\Gamma(\frac{N}{2}+1)}{(S(x)-z)^{\frac{N}{2}+1}}.$$

The coutour $C$ encloses the range of $S(x)$.